# AVCaptureDeviceInput initialization exception

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

When I try to create an instance of type AVCaptureDeviceInput I get the following error.
What have I done so far:
1) I have gain permissions for camera use and microphone.
2) I have tested the code on an iPhone 7 and an iPhone 5s.
3) When it displays the error I printed of the value of session.isRunning and it returns true value.
4) All the properties are retain strong.

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814 "Cannot Record" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Record, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again.
```

This is the code:

```
let session = AVCaptureSession()
self.session = session
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

do {
     let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
     session.addInput(input)
     if session.canAddInput(input) {
         let stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
         self.stillImageOutput = stillImageOutput
         let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
         stillImageOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
         if session.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
              session.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
              if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session) {
                   self.previewLayer = previewLayer
                   previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                   previewLayer.connection!.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                   viewController.centerView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
                   session.startRunning()
              }
          }
      }
} catch {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: How is the `device` being initialized?

Comment: as Oleg mentioned, check for device initialisation? Or can you add that code here.

Comment: @kapsym let device = AVCaptureDevice(uniqueID: AVMediaTypeVideo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues I find in your code, so the updated version with the comments on it would look like this:

```
let session = AVCaptureSession()
self.session = session
// `This method is used to start the flow of data from the inputs to the outputs connected to the AVCaptureSession instance that is the receiver.`
//session.startRunning() // Don't startRunning until everything is configured
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

do {
    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
//    session.addInput(input) // This one has to be after you check if you `canAddInput`
    if session.canAddInput(input) {
        session.addInput(input)
        let stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        self.stillImageOutput = stillImageOutput
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
//        stillImageOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self) // This one might want to be called after you add it as an output to the `session`
        if session.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            session.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session) {
                self.previewLayer = previewLayer
                previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                previewLayer.connection!.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                viewController.centerView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
                session.startRunning()
            }
            stillImageOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: .startRunning()  called on the 3rd line was for a test... i replaced the code with what you edit and i have the same error

Comment: Can you also try initializing your device like: `let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)`

Comment: Do you actually run the code on Simulator or on a Device? It seems the error usually comes when you don't have a connected device.

Comment: Oleg, as i mentioned, i tested this on iPhone 7 and iPhone 5S( real devices), i also deleted the apps and reinstalled them...

Comment: Did you also try initializing the device as suggested in the comment above?

Comment: add the initalization method as comment to the post, i want to give you the point :D thank you again

Comment: So initializing the device in the way I suggested did the trick?

Comment: Yes Oleg, now i must find out how to set the image that is showing in the preview layer to be square. My preview view is square, but the previewlayer is giving the image ratio as the device.